# What forces android activity to be destroyed when launching another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-billing

I'm trying to add in-app purchases and when I call 
`OpenIabHelper::launchPurchaseFlow` function:

- I see Google Play purchase window
- `onStop` and `onDestroy` are executed in my main activity without calls to `onActivityResult`

So in the end I left with GooglePlay window and my dead app

I tried to start another activity via `startActivityForResult` and it worked fine
(nothing was destroyed and `onActivityResult` was called), so it seems that problem is with [OpenIAB library](https://github.com/onepf/OpenIAB)

*Therefore there's my question:*
What can possibly force my activity to be destroyed after calling `OpenIabHelper::launchPurchaseFlow` ?

It doesn't seem to be system because it has enough memory and as I said 
`startActivityForResult` works fine.
Also there's no exceptions being trown so I'm puzzled

Any help would be appreciated
**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private OpenIabHelper m_helper;
    private Boolean m_bOpenIabInitialized = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        OpenIabHelper.Options.Builder builder = new OpenIabHelper.Options.Builder()
            .addAvailableStores(new GooglePlay(this,null))
            .addPreferredStoreName(OpenIabHelper.NAME_GOOGLE)
            .setStoreSearchStrategy(OpenIabHelper.Options.SEARCH_STRATEGY_INSTALLER_THEN_BEST_FIT)
            .setVerifyMode(OpenIabHelper.Options.VERIFY_SKIP)
            .setCheckInventory(false);
        m_helper = new OpenIabHelper(this, builder.build());
        m_helper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                m_bOpenIabInitialized = result.isSuccess();
            }
        });
    }


    public void onListViewItemClicked(String sku, String payload) {
        if (m_bOpenIabInitialized == null || !m_bOpenIabInitialized) return;
        m_helper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, sku, 10001, null, payload);
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int RequestCode) {
        // never reaches here
        Log.d(TAG, "startActivityForResult()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent data) {
        // never reaches here
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult()");
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|screenLayout">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: you are not able to test live products SKU  in your debug.apk

Comment: so, take care about it

Comment: @VishalPatoliya good to know, but in release the problem persists and google store activity works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the activity's launchMode? Maybe the *singleTop* launch mode will preserve your activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|screenLayout"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can find more about launch modes here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: I did some research following your launchMode suggestion and came to conclusion that it's the android system who closes my activity (I guess due it's resourcefulness (about 20MB of memory)). So anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this under the finishing activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Removing this solved the issue.